# What is the fastest way to get millions of external titles and descriptions?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have a Mysql table with columns URL, Title and Description. There are over six million rows, with each URL column having a url from the web. I now need to add the title and meta description for each url in the table. I got part of the job done by downloading the dmoz database and getting whatever titles and descriptions I could from there, but I still have several million url's left. I know this is going to be a long process, and I'm trying to figure out the quickest way to go about it.

I have the following code which uses CURL to get the Title and Meta:Decription from a url, but I'm not sure how to leverage it best with php to get the job done as quick as possible. I figure I should export the urls to a text file first, so we save a lookup to the db, but I'm not sure how to go from there. I have a dedicated server (E3-1230V2 with 32 GB) dedicated to this job, so the power is there, the question is how to use it best...

Any and all advice appreciated!

Here's the CURL code:

```
function get_info($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = get_info($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
$description = $meta->getAttribute('content');

insert into table SET Title ='".$title."', Description = '".$description."'
```

Comment: Have you considered companies that sell web-crawling-as-a-service? Fetching titles and metatags will be some of the simplest things they could do, beyond fetching tens of thousands of URLs per hour. https://www.google.com/search?q=crawling+as+a+service has some links to such companies, and I expect they will be able to do it faster, and ultimately cheaper than you could yourself.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I actually hasn't thought of that, and it's a great idea! Would you happen to know of any specific company who you think would be fitting for this job? There are so many out there!

Comment: I've used the results from 80legs.com before - they are listed on the first result of that search on the Quora answer.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I ended up taking your advice! I'd love for you to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered companies that sell web-crawling-as-a-service? Fetching titles and metatags will be some of the simplest things they could do, beyond fetching tens of thousands of URLs per hour. Searching for [crawling as a service](http://google.com/search?q=crawling+as+a+service) has some links to such companies, and I expect they will be able to do it faster, and ultimately cheaper than you could yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think most time is consumed by interaction with remote server via HTTP, not with your local database, so you probably can speed up process by spreading work among several processes running in parallel.  Then you need to run as many processes as needed to completely utilize your network bandwidth.